# While using FileReader class in java why is it compulsory to store the value of r.read in i first and then type caste it? why can't we typecast r.read

Tags: memory-management, filereader, file-handling, local-variables

[it is giving wrong output when I use f1.read directly .. why is it compulsory to use (i=f1.read) and then type caste i into the file .. why can't we use f1.read directly..] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQHnI.jpg)

```
//why this code is giving wrong output
// why is it compulsory to first store the value of f1.read in i

import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class third{

   public static void main(String [] args)  {
       try{
           FileReader f1 = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Akshita Agarwal\\Desktop\\a.txt");
           FileWriter f2 = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Akshita Agarwal\\Desktop\\b.txt");

           try{

               while(f1.read() !=-1){
                   f2.write((char)f1.read());
               }
           }
           finally {
               f2.close();
           }
       }
       catch(IOException e){
           out.println(e);
       }


   }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`char` is two bytes unsigned. `int -1` is outside this range.

Your code does not close `f1` and it writes half of the file, every second char.

It could be written as:

```
           for (;;) {
               int c = f1.read();
               if (c == -1) {
                   break;
               }
               f2.write((char)c);
           }
```

You suggestion

```
           for (;;) {
               char c = (char) f1.read();
               if (c == (char)-1) {
                   break;
               }
               f2.write(c);
           }
```

has one drawback.
You could embed a `((char) -1)` or `'\uFFFF'` in the middle of your file, and only
half of the file would be read.

The shortest code is:

```
           for (int c; (c = f1.read()) != -1;) {
               f2.write((char)c);
           }
```

However it:

- reads and writes per character
- there is a conversion reading from binary data using the platform encoding to (Unicode) text
- there is a conversion writing from (Unicode) text to binary data using the platform encoding.

Here you could do:

```
       Path path1 = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Akshita Agarwal\\Desktop\\a.txt");
       Path path2 = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop\\b.txt");
       Files.copy(path1, path2);
```

or read by lines:

```
       Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();
       try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path2, charset));
               Stream<String> reader = Files.lines(path1, charset)) {
           reader.forEach(line -> bw.write(line + "\r\n"));
       } // Automatically closes reader and writer.
```

The charset is needed to use the platform encoding. Per default it uses UTF-8, Unicode for the full range of possible characters for all languages.

Try-with-resources is a weird syntax `try (<DECLARATIONS>) { ... }` that ensures closing of the (auto-)closeable variables in the declarations. Even on `return`, `break` or exception.

The lines read are stripped from line endings CR-LF = "\r\n" (Windows), LF (Unix), CR, NEL (AS/400 e.a.).

Comment: Sir, I wanna ask that why is it compulsory to first store the value of f1.read in some integer, as in your code you used int c.  Why can't we access f1.read() directly..

why can't we use 
for ( ; ; ){
     if ( f1.read() == -1){
          break;
     }
     f2.write(f1.read());
}

Comment: `read()` return -1 at end-of-file, otherwise the next character (byte) read. So `read(); read();` will read two characters you can no longer know the value from.